# Passing a variable into a plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, global-variables

I am attempting to pass a variable into a plugin. I got the count to work when the var is wrapped within document.ready, but when I take it out of the document.ready so I can pass it to a different variable outside the document.ready, I am getting an undefined value.

The variable I want to add to the plugin (count all visible list items):

```
var myWidth = {};
var countLI = {};
myWidth.maxh = $("#my-carousel-2 .mask").width();
countLI.count = $("#my-carousel-2 ul li").filter(function () {
        return $(this).position().left + $(this).width() < myWidth.maxh;
    }).length;
```

The plugin I am attempting to apply the variable to: http://bit.ly/12v55TE.

More specifically, I want to pass the countLI.count variable length to the Carousel variable within the plugin.

Please help!

Comment: You are missing the `length` property.

Comment: oops. just added it, still not getting the count

Comment: length is property, not a function, you call it just like `.length;` not `.length();`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined value because the scope of the variable is within document.ready function. Try defining a global variable outside document.ready function and assign the count value to it. Then use in the plugin. That might help.

Comment: It is also possible to pass it to plugin as a custom option, and it will be available in plugin scope.

Comment: I took it out of the document.ready, when it was in it the count worked fine.

Comment: yabol can you elaborate on how I can do that?